# issue with 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to fill some data into two arrays, one containing normalized angles and another containing the `sin` of those angles. The arrays have to be 2D because they're going to be passed into a function that trains a neural network. I'm tried declaring a `[1][360]` array and got errors, so I've also tried `[1][]` as that's what intellisense is telling me, but then I got another problem.

Here is my code:

```
double[][] sin_in = new double[1][];
double[][] sin_out = new double[1][];
double deg = 0.0;
const double dtor = 3.141592654 / 180.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
{
    sin_out[0][i] =  Math.Sin(deg * dtor); // complains I need to use new
    sin_in[0][i] = deg / 360.0; //When I use new I get another error
    deg += 1.0;
}
IMLDataSet trainingSet 
    = new BasicMLDataSet(sin_in, sin_out); //Inputs must be [][]
```

So what mistakes/misunderstandings have I made?

Comment: Always remember to post the actual errors/exceptions you're getting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You initialize a two dimensional array like this:

```
double[,] sin_in = new double[1, 360];
double[,] sin_out = new double[1, 360];
double deg = 0.0;
const double dtor = 3.141592654 / 180.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
{
    sin_out[0,i] =  Math.Sin(deg * dtor); // complains I need to use new
    sin_in[0,i] = deg / 360.0; //When I use new I get another error
    deg += 1.0;
}
```

Oh, and by the way, the value of PI is built in in c# with as many decimals that fits in a double, use

```
const double dtor = Math.PI / 180.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using jagged arrays (aka. arrays of arrays). If you need multi-dimensional arrays, use the `double[,] array = new double[10,10];` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems like the function rejects multidimensional arrays but accepts jagged arrays. To form my jagged array correctly I changed my code to this:

```
        double[][] sin_in = new double[360][];
        double[][] sin_out = new double[360][];
        double deg = 0.0;
        const double dtor = Math.PI / 180.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            sin_out[i] =  new [] {Math.Sin(deg * dtor)};
            sin_in[i] =  new[] {deg / 360.0};
            deg += 1.0;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you even have a multidimensional array if one of the dimensions is only going to have a size of 1?

Comment: It's required by the constructor of the class `BasicMLDataSet` from a library I'm using.